# Git on a hosted remote server. What do I need from my host? What do I need to know?

Tags: git, web-hosting

This question will hopefully form a guide for people trying to do the same thing.

It would be useful to be able to use GIT to push and pull changes from production server. Most of us will not have the luxury of a personal server or data centre.

What attributes do we require from our web hosts in order to get git functioning, and what prerequisite knowledge do we require other than GIT skills?

Comment: Are you aware of github.com and gitorious.org?

Comment: yes, but I want to be able to run GIT from my live site server, so I can use git on my web apps, and be able to work on the local and live versions, using git as a bridge.

Answer (score 1):

> What do I need from my host?

The web host ideally need git and ssh installed. If they are running e.g. Apache on a unix environment, this is not an issue. I don't think that the web host need to have git skills, that is up to the person in charge of updating the web host from e.g. github.

Let me take an irl example. I'm in charge of developing a web site for a friend of mine that has a band. I develop and test the site locally and commit everything to a local git repository. When I'm satisfied with the results, I push up my changes to a repository on github. After this I just have to login via ssh to the web host and issue a "git pull" command, to syncronize the web host with the changes on github.